# RHEL5: Forbid installation of i386 packages on 64-bit systems?

Tags: rhel5, 64-bit, packages

Everytime I install something with yum, it tries to install both x86_64 and i386 versions of the package if both are available. Is there any way I can forbid that without specifying the arch of the package?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add **multilib_policy=best** to your **/etc/yum.conf**

Yum will now try to install the "best" package.arch for your system and it will only install that one (as long as it is available).

Assuming you're on a 64-Bit system, yum will first try to install package.x86_64, if that doesn't exist it will fall back to i386 and noarch.

The default setting is **multilib_policy=all**, which means to install all possible arches.

Comment: +1 Yes, that's the best answer. Unfortunately, most people don't now this option.

Answer (score 3):

I've been using option **exactarch=1** in **/etc/yum.conf** for some time, and it has worked for me.

It still allows you to manually specify arch, but if you don't, it install only x86_64, not both.

According to **el6** manual, **yum.conf(5)**:

> ```
>           exactarch  Either  ‘1’  or ‘0’. Set to ‘1’ to make yum update only update the architectures of
>           packages that you have installed. ie: with this enabled yum will not install an  i686  package
>           to update an i386 package. Default is ‘1’.
> ```

...

> ```
>           multilib_policy  Can  be set to ’all’ or ’best’. All means install all possible arches for any
>           package you want to install. Therefore yum install foo will install foo.i386 and foo.x86_64 on
>           x86_64, if it is available. Best means install the best arch for this platform, only.
> ```

BTW, both **multilib_policy=best** and **exactarch=1** seem to be the default for some time now.

Answer (score 2):

Use the exclude function in yum.conf:

```
exclude=*.i386 *.i686
```

Comment: Or `exclude=*.i?86` (/etc/yum.conf). That way, yum search won't even list 32-bit packages.

Answer (score 1):

It would try to install i386 version if you have x86_64 version already installed.

Pay attention that ***if you use exclude in yum.conf you could exclude packages only being available in i386 arch***

A safer way could be to **explicitly request the arch at install time**:

```
yum install package.x86_64
```

Answer (score 0):

-x, --exclude=package
              Exclude  a  specific package by name or glob from updates on all
              repositories.  Configuration Option: exclude

--disableexcludes=[all|main|repoid]
              Disable  the excludes defined in your config files. Takes one of
              three options:
              all == disable all excludes
              main == disable excludes defined in [main] in yum.conf
              repoid == disable excludes defined for that repo

above from man you can use or you can install yumex which give gui u can choose the rpm which you need to install.

http://www.yum-extender.org/blog/

Comment: I know about excludes, I just don't want to type them every time, neither do I want to create aliases. I just don't think installing i386 on 64-bit system by default is a good thing.

Comment: in that case you choose from gui that better options

Answer (score 0):

What works for me is removing all of the ix86 packages from the machine.  Now it never asks me to install any 32bit anything.

First setup your .rpmmacros like this:

```
cat ~/.rpmmacros
%_query_all_fmt %%{name}-%%{version}-%%{release}.%%{arch}
```

Then run this (I'm assuming bash):

```
rpm -qa | egrep "i.86$"
```

That will give you a list of non x86_64 rpms currently installed.  You can remove all of them with this:

```
rpm -e $(rpm -qa | egrep "i.x86$")
```

Now you have a pure 64bit system.

-Dave

Answer (score -3):

List i386

`yum list installed | grep i386`

And now you can remove it or update it to x86_64

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Although that might be useful to repair the situation, that is not an answer to the question how to prevent them getting installed in the first place...